# Selecting a subset of rows where a % of the values meet the threshold

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

I have a dataframe with values in rows and samples in columns (two groups, A and B). Example df:

```
df <- rbind(rep(1, times = 10), 
        c(rep(1, times = 9), 2), 
        c(rep(1, times = 8), rep(2, times = 2)),
        c(rep(1, times = 7), rep(2, times = 3)), rep(1, times = 10), 
        c(rep(1, times = 9), 2), 
        c(rep(1, times = 8), rep(2, times = 2)), 
        c(rep(2, times = 7), rep(1, times = 3)))
colnames(df) <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5",
              "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")
row.names(df) <- 1:8
```

I have been selecting subset of rows where all samples are below a certain threshold using the following:

```
selected <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x < 1.5))
df.sel <- df[selected,]
```

result of this is

```
df[c(1,5),]
```

I require two further type of selections. The first is to select, for example, all rows where at least 90% of the samples are below the threshold values of 1.5. The result of this should be:

```
df[c(1,2,5,6)]
```

The second is to select by group. Say, rows where at least 50% of values in at least one of the groups is > that 1.5. This should give me the following df:

```
df[c(4,8),]
```

I am new to Stackoverflow and i have been asked in the past to put example. I hope this is good!

Comment: If you add the language as tag is easier to find developers that can help you

Comment: Done, sorry about that and thanks!

Comment: a) Can you make your dataframe values more varied? It's nearly all-ones b) Don't shadow the builtin `select` by declaring a variable `select`

Comment: `apply(df, MARGIN = 1, ...)` can be obviated, in this case (nearly all-ones) you can cheat with e.g. `df[rowMeans(df)<1.5, ]`

Comment: @Jake: my mistake. I was thinking of the `select` argument of `subset(..., select=...)`, someone posted a question about shadowing that with a variable `select`, it caused confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[!rowSums(df >= 1.5),]
##   A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
## 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
## 5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

df[rowMeans(df < 1.5) >= 0.9,]
##   A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
## 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
## 2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2
## 5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
## 6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2

idx <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    any(tapply(x, gsub("[0-9]", "", names(x)), function(y) mean(y > 1.5)) > 0.5)
    })

df[idx,]
##   A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
## 4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2
## 8  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1
```

Comment: @ Jake, thanks very much. Your solutions applied fine to my real dataset (the third one made me happy!). I have two questions though, i didnt understand why you used !rowSums and not rowMeans. It does work, but i dont understand why. Shouldn't the sum of row 1 be 10? That should not show up in the output if i understand.
My other question is about your third example. If i want to select mean(y>1.5) in 80% of my sample i shall adjust to >0.2. Is this correct? Thanks again, unfortunately i can't vote up!

Comment: @ChristianD `rowSums` is being called on `df >= 1.5` which is a `data.frame` filled with `logical`s. Look at the output of just `df >= 1.5` to see. So `rowSums(df >= 1.5)` will be the number of values greater than or equal to 1.5 in each row. `!rowSums(df >= 1.5)` is equivalent to `rowSums(df >= 1.5) != 0`. In the third example you would change it to `> 0.8`. Try it out on this sample data and see which rows get returned! I'll add this into the answer with more explanation when I get a chance later today

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case of nearly all-ones, you can do all this with `rowMeans` or `colMeans`. (There is also `plyr::colwise` for more complicated stuff).

Select subset of rows where all samples are below a certain threshold using the following:

```
df[rowMeans(df)<1.5,]
```

Select all rows where >=90% of samples are below the threshold value of 1.5.
(would be much easier if we can exploit knowing that the only other value is 2)

You can directly count the proportion of '1' entries with:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x==1)) /ncol(df)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
1.0 0.9 0.8 0.7 1.0 0.9 0.8 0.3
```

Thus to get the row-indices you want:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x==1)) /ncol(df) >= 0.9
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

and the row-slice you want:

```
> df[ apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x==1)) /ncol(df) >= 0.9 , ]
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2
5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2
```

> The second is to select by group. Say, rows where at least 50% of values in at least one of the groups is > that 1.5.

Unless I misunderstand what you meant by 'at least one of the groups',
your example's wrong. Row 4 doesn't qualify, only row 8.

Again, you could either cheat with `rowSums`, or else:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x>=1.5)) /ncol(df) >= 0.5
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

That only gets you row 8 not 4, so have I misunderstood you?
(Jake Burhead clarifies you are doing hierarchical indexing by string name of column. See his solution, there's no point in me reproducing it.)

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the groups as well. The groups seem to come from the letter in the column name. So row 4 gets selected because it has 3 of 5 greater than 1.5 in the B group

Comment: @Jake-Burhead thanks! So like hierarchical indexing on the columns...?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the solutions. I am sorry if the example was probably reductive. I should have put more effort into preparing the df. My fault, will do that next time!

Comment: ChristianD, for a new user you're great. It's cool. Except it's nice to upvote helpful answers...

Comment: I wish i could but it tells me i have got not enough reputations. Plus i tried to put the green tick to both answers but i can only select one! I am doing my best.. :)